# Missing file System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.Net Core 3 project in Visual Studio using the standard MVC template. After updating VS to 16.4.6, I could not run the project anymore. I can build without issues, but attempting to run will give:

[image]

How do I fix this error? I did not make any explicit changes to my .NET environment (other than updating VS).

Comment: Do you run with project or IIS express?Could you try closing vs ,opening again to build a new mvc project and  running with `dotnet run`?

Comment: I simply pressed F5, and a CMD window shows `....\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\myprogram.dll`. How do I tell if it is using IIS Express? Now the Project menu has no Properties anymore.

Comment: You could run with IIS express from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJoPl.png)

Comment: It is ok now. Apparently, I opened the *folder* containing the solution instead of opening the solution. There were no obvious indicators that I opened the wrong thing. I could still build (Ctrl-B instead of Ctrl-Shift-B), whatever that means. Thanks for getting me out of the rut.